# Main Activity Destroyed before Splash Screen return

Tags: java, android, android-intent, splash-screen

I have a Main Activity from where I call an Splash Screen Intent which destroys itself after 3 seconds but between the lifecycle of the Splash Screen Intent the Main Activity destroys itself too (which is wrong!).. so when the Splash Screen Intent is finished the App crashes because the Main Activity has been destroyed itself.

I really Appreciate if someone can help me with this, I'm really out of ideas at this point.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webview;

    public MainActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        log.debug("onCreate(): " + savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.startSomeMobileCore(this);
        MyApplication.startSomeMobileNotifier(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.onNewIntent(this.getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        log.debug("onStart()");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        this.wasRestarted = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.receivedIntent = false;
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        this.receivedIntent = false;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        log.debug("onNewIntent(): " + intent);
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        if(intent == null) {
            log.warn("Received null intent, will ignore");
        }

        if ("OK".equals(authCode)) {
            if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null &&
                ("content".equals(intent.getData().getScheme()) || 
                "http".equals(intent.getData().getScheme()))) {
                log.debug("intent.getData() :" + intent.getData() + "; intent.getData().getScheme() : " + intent.getData().getScheme());
                String requestedPath;
                if ("http".equals(intent.getData().getScheme())) {
                    requestedPath = URLDecoder.decode(intent.getData().toString());
                } else {
                    requestedPath = intent.getData().getPath();
                }
                showResource(requestedPath);
            } else {
                log.debug("Intent without data -> go to entry page after splash screen");
            showResource(Configuration.properties.getProperty("PORTAL"));
            }
        } else {
            Intent errorIntent = new Intent(this, ErrorIntent.class);
            startActivity(errorIntent);
            // finish actual activity
            finish();
        }

        log.debug("Show splash screen");
        Intent intentSplash = new Intent(this, SplashIntent.class);
        startActivity(intentSplash);
    }

    void showResource(String resourceToShow) {
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
        webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl(resourceToShow);
    }
}
```

}

here is my SplashIntent.java

```
public class SplashIntent extends Activity {
    // Time splash screen should be shown (in ms)
    private static final int splashTime = 3000;
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SplashIntent.class);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        log.debug("SplashIntent: onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 log.debug("SplashIntent: killing splash");
                 finish();
             }
        }, splashTime);

    }
}
```

here is a  [part of logcat](http://pastebin.com/NTViyZgJ)

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. `this.onNewIntent(this.getIntent());` is called from `onCreate`. The default value of `authCode` likely isn't `OK` so you will start the `ErrorIntent` activity, `finish()` your `MainActivity`, and then also start the `SplashIntent` activity. How do you want this to work exactly? When is `authCode` set?

Comment: After all those validations, always displays the Splash Screen (3 seconds) then the Main Activity @GeorgeMulligan

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to override onNewInent in your MainActivity.

In the onCreate() method use the following:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null){
    Intent splashIntent = new Intent(this, SplashIntent.class);
    startActivity(splashIntent);
}
```

This will start the splash screen whenever the MainActivity is initialized without a saved state. Since your SplashIntent activity calls finish after it is done it should revert to the last activity in the stack (aka your MainActivity).

---

An even better way to do this would be to use your SplashIntent activity as your launcher activity and then forward the user to the MainActivity using an intent.

Very simple example would be:

```
public class SplashIntent extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    log.debug("SplashIntent: onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             log.debug("SplashIntent: killing splash");
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             finish();
         }
    }, splashTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, still following your solution I'm getting a cycle and the Splash executes over and over again without reach MainIntent . @Helix

Comment: It sounds like you used the second suggestion but didn't remove the splash launch intent from the main Activity. Remove the startActivity(intentSplash) from the main activity class.

Comment: Already remove the startActivity(intentSplash) from the main activity class, remains the problem.

Comment: The work flow should look like this: Launch into splash screen directly -> call intent to start main activity & finish splash screen -> run code to check for validation in the onCreate method.... remember that the activity will continue to run after a new activity is started. Also I don't understand why you are overriding the onNewIntent() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try startActivityForResult to launch splash screen (SplashIntent).

instead of

```
Intent intentSplash = new Intent(this, SplashIntent.class); 
startActivity(intentSplash);
```

Try the below

```
startActivityForResult
```

And then from SplashIntent.java

```
Intent i = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i); //pass your result
finish(); // Call finish to remove splash from the stack
```

Ref link :
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Sample code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final int SHOW_SPLASH_SCREEN_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showSplashSCreen();
   }

   private void showSplashSCreen() {
       Intent intentSplash = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
       startActivityForResult(intentSplash, 
                                   SHOW_SPLASH_SCREEN_REQUEST);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                     Intent data) {
       // Check which request we're responding to
       if (requestCode == SHOW_SPLASH_SCREEN_REQUEST) {
           // Make sure the request was successful
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              // code to handle anything after splash screen finished.
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Splash Screen :

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final int splashTime = 3000;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // optional per your requirement
            setResult(MainActivity.SHOW_SPLASH_SCREEN_REQUEST);
            // must call finish
            finish();
        }
    }, splashTime);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, Still get the same error. @Pattabiraman V

Comment: can you point the parameters you put in startActivityForResult(?, ?)

Comment: MainActivity Still destroying itself before Splash Screen Result.